# Arrays and loops through days

Tags: php, arrays, codeigniter, loops

I have a problem creating this function. My code is a mess and I'm stuck, so I'd rather not post it. I'd rather ask for a fresh solution.

I have an array (mysql rows), fetched with today's date as a condition. I want to create a new array based on data from the previous array and insert it into the database also by today's date. Limit is 15. So if there are already 10 rows by this date, insert only 5, and continue on the next date, for as long as there are rows from the first array.

I am using php and code igniter.

Comment: Which aspect are you stuck on? How to query the data? How to count the results? How to create a specific number of new entries? How to insert those new entries back into the database?

Comment: i am stuck at creating loops and conditions i would say. Query data and inserting back to the database is ok.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know how you're fetching the data or how you are generating new data, but something like this;

```
//loop through days that you want to check/update
    //fetch existing data for this day into $data
    if( count( $data ) >= 15 ) continue; //skip days that already have 15+
    for( $x = 0; $x < 15 - count( $data ); $x++ )
    {
        //insert one new row here
    }
//end days loop
```

Comment: Thank you verv. Can you tell me please how to post a section of code in here?(i am new) I will post my code then to be easier to understand.

Comment: Indent each line and it automatically becomes code. 4 spaces indent :) You can also mark small bits mid-sentence as code like `this` by surrounding it with two back ticks (the one on the tilde key).

Comment: This is how i am fetching data: `$subscriptions = Subscription::all(array('conditions' => 'token != "" '));` start time is `$startTime = strtotime('today'); `, in Y-m-d format.  Now what i am trying to achieve is to go through all the subscriptions, process it, and insert into another table. I'm checking it with : `$projects = Project::all(array('conditions' => 'end = "'.date("Y-m-d", $startTime).'" '));` so if there are no projects for that day or < 15 i will insert new to populate up to 15 (from subscriptions). Then go to next day `$startTime = strtotime('+1 day', $startTime);`.

Answer (score 0):

Here is how i did it and it does what i want it to do. Not sure if it is the best way to achieve this functionality. Here i was using a temporary array just for testing. Each element will be a new row for the database. Used 3 as maximum(instead of 15) for testing only.

```
    $subscriptions = Subscription::all(array('conditions' => 'token != "" ', 'order' => 'id asc'));
    $startTime = strtotime('2013-08-15'); 

    $temparray = array();

    $projects = Project::all(array('conditions' => 'end = "'.date("Y-m-d", $startTime).'" '));
    if ($projects){$counter = count($projects);}else{$counter = 0;}

    while (list($key, $value) = each($subscriptions))
    {
        if ($counter == 3)
        {
            do
            {
                $startTime = strtotime('+1 day', $startTime);
                $projects = Project::all(array('conditions' => 'end = "'.date("Y-m-d", $startTime).'" '));
                if (count($projects) < 3)
                    {
                        $counter = count($projects);
                        break;
                    }
            } while ($counter <= 3);

                $temparray[] = $value->date . " " . date("Y-m-d", $startTime);
                continue;   
        }

    $temparray[] = $value->date . " " . date("Y-m-d", $startTime);
    $counter++;
    }
```